# Reuse collection of files in different tasks in Ant?

Tags: ant, build

I have a set of files in several directories which I would like to zip, and then delete.

`fileset`s seem to require specification of a specific dir, and it looks like `patternset`s can be reused, but I'd still have to have multiple `fileset`s (and it seems that `fileset` is  a ["legacy" datatype](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#collection)).

`files` might be what I'm after, but I don't see a way to reuse a list of files using it.

I would expect to be able to do something like this:

```
<files id="myfiles" includes="artifacts.jar content.jar 
        /plugins/*.jar /features/*.jar" />

<target name="zip">
    <zip destfile="dest.zip">
        <files ref="myfiles">
    </zip>
</target>

<target name="clean">
    <delete>
        <files ref="myfiles">
    </delete>
</target>
```

What is the cleanest way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A path holds nested resources, f.e. filesets

```
<project default="main">

   <path id="myfiles">
      <fileset dir="/path/to/some/dir">
         <include name="**/*.xml"/>
      </fileset>
      <fileset dir="/path/to/some/other/dir">
         <include name="**/*.xslt"/>
      </fileset>
      <!-- ... -->
   </path>

   <target name="zip">
      <zip destfile="dest.zip">
         <path refid="myfiles"/>
      </zip>
   </target>

   <target name="clean">
      <delete>
         <path refid="myfiles"/>
      </delete>
   </target>

   <target name="main" depends="zip,clean"/>

</project>
```

Comment: This does actually seem to work, but the `zip` task gives me a warning `[zip] Warning: skipping zip archive C:\temp\521.zip because no files were included.` and even though the next line is `[zip] Building zip: C:\temp\521.zip` (and there's only 1 zip task in a target which only runs once). I'll accept this answer since it is probably the correct way to do it, but I've documented my solution as well.

Comment: "no files were included" means the pattern didn't match any file because of empty directory or the pattern has to be adjusted to match the files you want. A simple way to check whether your pattern matches is to echo the contents of a path with <echo>${toString:pathid}</echo> or the contents of a fileset with <echo>${toString:filesetid}</echo>

Comment: I should have mentioned that the files I specified **were** included in the zip, despite the warning.

Comment: What's your environment = Ant version, OS, Java.. ?

Comment: I was running my build script from Eclipse 3.6.2 (i.e. using whatever version of ant Eclipse 3.6.2 comes with), running on the IBM JDK 6 (64-bit), on Windows 7 x64. Have you tried your example, and if it works, what version of Ant did you test with?

Comment: seems like you hit that bug = https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50115 - which is fixed in version Ant 1.8.2 Check the version that ships with eclipse via <echo>${ant.version}</echo> Download ant 1.8.2 and change eclipse settings Window | Preferences | Ant | Runtime | Ant Home to use that version

Answer (score 0):

I ended up accomplishing this by having the `fileset`'s `dir` be the root and using multiple `include` elements inside the `fileset` to include particular files in particular sub-directories. Something like this:

```
<fileset dir="." id="fileset.my_files">
    <include name="file1.jar" />
    <include name="dir1/*.jar" />
</fileset>

<target name="build_zip">
    <zip destfile="${dist}/${zip.file}">
        <fileset refid="fileset.my_files" />
    </zip>
</target>

<!-- etc -->
```